# Calculate Field to remove time from datetime Python

Tags: python, arcpy

I want to calculate the value of a new field by grabbing the date only (strip out the time) from the existing field DATE_VAL.

I keep getting errors however. Here is my code.

```
formatter_string = "%m%d%y"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("joined", "Date", dt.strftime("!DATE_VAL!", formatter_string), "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

If I try the following:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("joined", "Date", "dt.strftime(!DATE_VAL!, formatter_string).date()", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

I get the following error:
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: dt.strftime(u"5/1/2014 3:00:00 AM", formatter_string).date()

When I try the following:

```
formatter_string = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"

arcpy.CalculateField_management("joined", "Date",
     dt.strptime("!DATE_VAL!", formatter_string).date(), "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

I get the error: ValueError: time data '!DATE_VAL!' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'

Comment: What is the value of `DATE_VAL`?

Comment: It varies. It is a field in my attribute table.

Comment: This question would be highly suited to the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.datetime` objects have a `date` method that will return a `datetime.date` object.

```
formatter_string = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"

arcpy.CalculateField_management("joined", "Date",
         "dt.strptime(!DATE_VAL!, formatter_string).date()", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Comment: I get the error: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'. DATE_VAL is a date field.

Comment: @Andrew I haven't used arcpy. You seemed to have code that gave you a datetime object when you needed a date object. Can you edit your question to be more specific about your problem?

Comment: @Andrew does `"!DATE_VAL!"` resolve to something like `"013198"` or etc? If so, you should be using `strptime` not `strftime`

Comment: No it doesn't. I added to my question just now. Thanks.

Comment: `"5/1/2014 3:00:00 AM"` looks like `"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"` to me. Try stripping with that

Comment: I get the following error: ValueError: time data '!DATE_VAL!' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' when using the updated formatter string: formatter_string = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"

Comment: You keep changing your mind on what your error is. One minute you've got text transposing correctly, the next you have a NameError, the next your text isn't transposing. Please sort out your code and edit your question with the ACTUAL problem

Comment: I got a different error message due to the update formatter_string. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Andrew fixed. Your original code didn't match the code you posted with the `ExecuteError` I was fixing originally.

Answer (score 0):

I found some code to use update cursor rather than the calculate field. This seems to work for my purpose. I probably should have posted this in the gis stack exchange. sorry.

```
arcpy.AddField_management("joined", "Date", "DATE")
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("joined")
for row in rows:
    datetimeVal = row.getValue("DATE_VAL")
    formattedTime = dt.strftime(datetimeVal, "%m/%d/%Y")
    row.setValue("Date", formattedTime)
    rows.updateRow(row)
del rows, row
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not the arcpy guy but this should do:

Instead of:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("joined", "Date", "dt.strftime(!DATE_VAL!, formatter_string).date()", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Do this:

```
date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'
formatter_string = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
arcpy.CalculateField_management("joined", "Date", "dt.strftime(!DATE_VAL!, formatter_string).date().strftime(date_format)", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```